# react - stop scrolling when reaching specific section

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Current UI:

[image]

When I want to do is, when the scroll arrives to the red section, the percentage will start increasing
[image]
User cannot continue to scroll down until the percentage increases to 100%.
[image]

Example:
https://circleci.com/#advantage-flexibility

How to do it?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useScrollPercentage } from "react-scroll-percentage";

export default function App() {
  const [ref, percentage] = useScrollPercentage({
    /* Optional options */
    threshold: 0
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>{" "}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div ref={ref} style={{ color: "red" }}>
        <h1>
          When the scroll arrive this div, the position of this div will become
          sticky, and the percentage will start to increase from 0 to 100. When
          arriving 100%, user can then scroll to next section
        </h1>
        <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2)}%.`}</h2>
      </div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesnadbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-bird-9fy50?file=/src/App.js:0-1365

Comment: Hey @CCCC, please tell me which solution works to award them the bounty.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS to do that!

scroll-snap-stop is part of the CSS Scroll Snap Module. Scroll snapping refers to “locking” the position of the viewport to specific elements on the page as the window (or a scrollable container) is scrolled. Think of a scroll-snapping container like putting a magnet on top of an element that sticks to the top of the viewport and forces the page to stop scrolling right there.

scroll-snap-stop allows you to force the scroll-snapping container to snap to a particular element. Suppose you were scrolling within a scroll-snapping container, and you gave it a giant spin-of-the-mousewheel. Normally, the browser would let the velocity of your scrolling fly past snap points until it settled on a snap point close to where the scrolling would normally end. By setting scroll-snap-stop you can tell the browser that it must stop on a particular element before allowing the user past it.

You can check more info --> [scroll-snap-stop (css-tricks.com)](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-snap-stop/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30993957)

Answer (score 2):

1. write an `event.listener` for the scroll of the page (the tag that holds all the text) using `useRef` in `react-hooks`
2. find the y-axis value of the ref you just created where you want to stop scrolling.
3. have state that holds the percentages, and a state for the y-axis the user is now.
4. when the percentages aren't 100 and the desired y-axis value of the current ref is reached, stop the scroll for the ref you defined earlier.
5. when percentages changed to 100, or the user scroll back up, (which means current y-axis is smaller than stopping point) allow scroll again.

Comment: Please show the result on Codesandbox if you want the +100 rep bounty award.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Gsap [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger) to achieve the desired result on https://circleci.com .

Demo on [codesandbox](https://fsg5z.csb.app/)

```html
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [tween, setTween] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tween) return;

    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    let scrollTween = gsap.to(ref.current, {
      ease: "none",
      backgroundColor: "#DAF7A6",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ref.current,
        pin: true,
        anticipatePin: 1,
        invalidateOnRefresh: true,
        refreshPriority: 1,
        start: "top 0%",
        end: "+=300%",
        markers: false,
        toggleActions: "play reset play reset",
        onUpdate: (self) => {
          let p = (self.progress * 100).toFixed(1);
          setProgress(p);
        }
      }
    });

    setTween(scrollTween);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="top">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>{" "}
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
      <div ref={ref} id="hscroll">
        <h1>
          When the scroll arrive this div, the position of this div will become
          sticky, and the percentage will start to increase from 0 to 100. When
          arriving 100%, user can then scroll to next section
        </h1>
        <h2 id="output">{`Percentage scrolled: ${progress}%.`}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```